# How do I calculate the long term Brokerage service cost for my dollar cost averaged investments?

Tags: investing, calculation, fees, netherlands

I'm currently in the middle of comparing brokerage firms cost-wise. One brokerage firm charges its service fee based on an annual rate that is charged monthly. Since I want to employ dollar cost averaging, the service fees rise every month. How do I calculate the total amount of service cost paid after a 25 year period?

I believe this is an arithmetic sequence since the structure would look like this:

```
MP = Monthly service fee percentage
AP = Anual service fee percentage
I = Initial investment
M = Monthly investment
N = Period (1-300)
SF_N = Service fee in period N

MP = AP / 12
SF_1 = I*MP
SF_2 = I*MP + M*MP
SF_3 = I*MP + 2M*MP
SF_N = I*MP + (N-1)M*MP
```

Is this correct? Would the total sum after 25 years then be:

```
S = (25*12*(I*MP + (I*MP + (300-1)M*MP)))/2
```

Comment: Are you planning to have someone manage your money, or invest on your own? Nothing is free, but there's quite the difference between the 5 basis points (i.e. .05%) an ETF will charge, and a 1% management fee layered on top of the investment itself.

Comment: I'm investing myself. This is simply the service fee they charge. This doesn't include transaction fees.

Comment: You should not have any service fees. Some brokers even offer a number of ETFs with no trade cost. You're buying/selling the ETF for free and just paying the ETF expense. You can do the math above if you really want to be scared straight.

Comment: https://www.binck.nl/fondsbeleggen/fundcoach Their pricing structure is about halfway down the page

Comment: Many do. And I respectfully say "good for them." Because many don't. In the US, Schwab, Fidelity, Vanguard are among the ones I'd use.

Comment: I don't believe it is possible in the Netherlands to purchase ETF's and funds without a broker or bank?

Comment: I added the Netherlands tag. We tend to start an answer assuming our own country. I'd continue to search to see if I could do better. The good news is a 360/yr maximum fee. So on 1M, under .04% added cost. Still, keep looking.

Comment: One thing you are not accounting for is how your net equity will change over time.  The service fee is applied each period to the net equity in the account.  Therefore, in addition to your cumulative monthly investments, you should assume a certain rate of return so that you equity and service charges change accordingly.  Also, I agree with JoeTaxpayers comment that you should shop around.  You should be able to find brokerage without service fees.

Comment: @NickR I hadn't thought of that at all. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Problem is, I want to employ dollar cost averaging. So I'm either going to pay substantial service fees or substantial transaction fees. Worst case both. Brokers have to earn their money apparently.

Comment: As I described, we can find a broker with no "service fee" and an offering of transaction free etfs. This pushes our annual costs down to less than .1% per year.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Is that broker also available for private investors?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about. They typically handle large company retirement plans, too, but my answer is based on the individual investor, like you and me.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I found a broker which offers both zero service and transactional fees for ETF's that sort of resemble my original selection. I'll keep this thread open for people looking to calculate their monthly service fees as I believe this is the correct methodology (without monthly gain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DeGiro offers a free account with free etf transactions. For this they have a 'fair use policy' (no active trading), but I assume your dollar averaging involves less than 1 transaction per etf per month.

Comment: Exactly what I'm doing now! Doubting about the amount of ETF's I trade in though. Currently around 8 and it's yielding okay results but nothing compared to the S&P 500.

Comment: With 8 etf's you're probably diversified enough. Optimizing any further won't get you significantly improvements, in my opinion. Next to diversification you control the costs (as you know) and your risk apitite. Just stay disciplined.